# Apply center position to the gallery but not to the pictures

Tags: html, css, gallery, centering, text-align

My website is composed of a fixed sidebar and a wrap which contains a gallery. The gallery is successfully centered within the wrap, but my problem is that the text-align:center property is also applied to the pictures

I haven't enough reputation points to post a second picture, but basically I would like the fifth picture to be under the first one.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jean Iturralde</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Portfolio de Jean Iturralde"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.backstretch("img/wooden.png");
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="sidebar">
    <header>
        <h1><a href="#">Jean Iturralde</a></h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
     </header>

    <div id="circle_pic">
        <div id="circle_pic_hover"><p>Jean<br />62 ans<br />Peintre<br /></p></div>
    </div>

    <section>
        <div class="sidebar_title"><img src="img/quotes.png" class="icon" /><h2>Bienvenue,</h2></div>
        <p class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae magna quam, commodo vulputate nulla. Mauris fringilla mi sapien, in semper turpis. Aliquam consequat magna nec magna egestas vitae aliquet turpis lacinia. Praesent commodo commodo scelerisque. Maecenas dui urna, egestas vel commodo quis, adipisci.</p>
    </section>

    <footer>
       <p>
        Jean Iturralde<br />
        Tous droits réservés<br />
        </p>
    </footer>

</div>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="content">
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><div class="boxcontent">
            <img src="img/tableau_1.jpg">
            <div class="meta">
                <h2>Tableau 1<h2>
                <h3>2013 - Acryllique - 81x65 cm</h3>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><div class="boxcontent">
            <img src="img/tableau_2.jpg">
            <div class="meta">
                <h2>Tableau 2<h2>
                <h3>2013 - Acryllique - 81x65 cm</h3>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><div class="boxcontent">
            <img src="img/tableau_3.jpg">
            <div class="meta">
                <h2>Tableau 2<h2>
                <h3>2013 - Acryllique - 81x65 cm</h3>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><div class="boxcontent">
            <img src="img/tableau_4.jpg">
            <div class="meta">
                <h2>Tableau 4<h2>
                <h3>2013 - Acryllique - 81x65 cm</h3>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><div class="boxcontent">
            <img src="img/tableau_5.jpg">
            <div class="meta">
                <h2>Tableau 4<h2>
                <h3>2013 - Acryllique - 81x65 cm</h3>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans500';
    src: url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.svg#museo_sans500') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body{
    margin:0;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:720px;
    background-color:white;
    padding:15px 30px 0 30px;
    width:260px;
    text-align:center;
}

header h1{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

header h1 a{
    color:#303030;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
}

header ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
}

header li a{
    float:left;
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
    font-size:15px;
    color:#afafaf;
    transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    -o-transition: all 500ms;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms;
    border-top:solid 7px #ababab;
    padding:8px 8px 0 8px;
}

header li a:hover{
    color:black;
    border-top:solid 7px #303030;
}

header li a.active{
    color:black;
    border-top:solid 7px #303030;
}

#circle_pic{
    width:174px; height:174px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 87px; -moz-border-radius: 87px;
    background:url(img/profilepic.png) no-repeat;
    margin:70px 0 20px 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#circle_pic_hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:auto; height:175px;
    margin-top:175px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}

#circle_pic_hover p{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:27px;
    margin-top:45px;

}


#circle_pic:hover #circle_pic_hover{
    margin-top:0;
}

section{
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.sidebar_title{
    text-align:left;
}

.icon{
    margin-bottom:-2px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:inline;
    height:30px;
}

#sidebar h2{
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    font-size:29px;
    color:#d9d9d9;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
}

.main_text{
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
    color:#252525;
    margin-top:0;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:25px;
}

footer {
    width:260px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:5px;
    margin-left:-130px;
}

footer p{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
    color:#959595;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

footer a{
    color:#353535;
}

#wrap{
    position:absolute;
    left:320px;
    top:30px;
    right:0;
}

#content{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

/*******/

.box {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:24%;
    padding-bottom:31%;
}

.boxcontent {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.boxcontent img{
    width:100%;
}

.boxcontent .meta{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom:-52px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
}

.meta h2,h3{
    color:#b0b0b0;
    margin:0;
}

.meta h2{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.meta h3{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
}

.boxcontent:hover .meta{
    margin-bottom:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */

   .box {
      width: 76%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }

   #sidebar{
    position:static;
    margin-top:0;
    width:100%;
    min-height:0;
    height:120px;
   }

   header{
    width:280px;
    margin:0 auto;
   }


   nav ul{
    margin:0 0 0 -15px;
   }

   #circle_pic, section, footer{
    display:none;
   }

   #wrap{
    position:static;
    margin-top:30px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 76%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1390px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 38%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the way you are positioning `#sidebar` and `#wrap` to start with.

I would change the styles on `#sidebar` to be:

```
#sidebar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 720px;
    padding: 15px 30px 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16%;
}
```

All I have done on this is removed the hard-coded `width: 260px` to make the design a little bit easier to work with and removed the redundant `left: 0`. If I was to continue refining the design I would change other declarations slightly but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Next, I would change the style of `#wrap` to be:

```
#wrap {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 78%;
}
```

And finally change the style of `.box` to be:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 31%;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Obviously you can play with the margins and widths to get the design looking exactly as you want but this should get you into a rough position.

Comment: He is centering the list by using `text-align:center;` which means floating the boxes left pushes the whole list outside of the center.

Comment: When I apply a float:left to the class box, the gallery is no longer centered.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't understand the question quite correctly. In that case I was still suggest using `float:left` on the `box` class and change the way `#wrap` is being positioned. I would advise against absolute positioning.

Comment: I had problems with #wrap because of the fixed sidebar on the left. Absolute positionning was the only solution I found to have a centered gallery on the right side of the page. Is there another solution I didn't think about ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Indeed, that put me into a rough position. I tried playing with the media queries to fix the way it looks, but it's a bit sloppy. I guess I will get used to that second row being centered, it's not that of a big deal. Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `text:align: center` to `text-align:left` for `#content`, unless this introduces a problem I cannot see (?)

Comment: When I try text-align:left, my gallery is no longer centered in the wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than aligning the images with a `text-align`, you can use `float:left;` instead. However, based one your current CSS/HTML, this moves the images too far to the left. What you can do instead, if change the way the entire list is being centered.

So:

```
#content {
    padding:0 12%;
    /* remove the text-align declaration */
}

.box {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

This would be a more flexible layout. Play with the values to get the sizes you want (the padding value, for example... this can be a % or em or px value here, because the `.box` is % based.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) pseudo-class:

```
.box:last-child {
    float: left;
    left: 121px;
}
```

Comment: By changing the value of left it looks like what I want but when I resize the page it doesn't work anymore. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table in the place of using the divs in order to force the images into the layout you want. Then no need to worry about the text-align: center; in your content block.